# Firefox doens't update Silverlight Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, silverlight

i have a problem with Firefox and Silverlight. I have a silverlight application (with version-number 1.0.0.0) on my website. Now I have modified the silverlight application(version-number is now 1.0.0.1) and replaced the old file on the server with my new application.

The Internet Explore loads the new application correctly. But unfortunally the Firefox 4 still loads the old Silverlight application.

Is there a trick to fix this issue or have i to rename the xap file on every update?

Than You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be Firefox cached that xap and load cahced one.
If you wont do load xap every time user opens the page, then replace

```
 <param name="source" value="ClientBin/YourXapName.xap" />
```

with this one

```
        <%
            string orgSourceValue = @"ClientBin/YourXapName.xap";
            string param;    
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)    
                param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "\" />";
            else
            {
                string xappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" + orgSourceValue;
                DateTime xapCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath);        
                param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "?ignore=" + xapCreationDate.ToString() + "\" />";
            }
            Response.Write(param);
         %>
```

Comment: Placing 4 spaces or a tab in front each line of code in a code block is enough for SO rendering to recognising it as code.  Easiest way to include code is to simply paste it in, select it and press the { } button.

Comment: +1 and here is a great explanation of how the new XAP file is loaded each time:
http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2010/02/avoid-incorrect-caching-of-silverlight-xap-file/

Comment: Has no one noticed HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" + orgSourceValue gives you something like "c:\...\ClientBin/YourXapName.xap", which is invalid? Why not just map the path to the original source value?